# Lose pointer to Delegate while going through Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, delegates, uinavigationcontroller, segue, popover

I am not entirely sure how to explain my problem but I will try.

So I have been trying to learn how to use delegates and protocols and ran into a problem. I have a protocol: ButtonInPopOverWasPressed, with one method:

```
   - (void)buttonWasPressed:(NSString *)buttonValue;
```

I also have a main view controller and a custom popover class with the property:

```
   @property (retain, nonatomic) id <ButtonInPopoverWasPressed> delegate;
```

In my main view controller I have a button and a text label. When the button is pressed it segue's to a normal popover. I then assign the segue.destinationViewController's delegate to be the main view controller like so:

```
   [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
```

Then when a button from the popover is selected it is displayed in the main view's text label by calling a protocol method that the main view listens for:

```
   [self.delegate buttonWasPressed:sender.currentTitle]; // sends the title of the button pressed to the delegate
```

This all works fine. My problem started when I wanted to have the popover transition to different views when a button was pressed instead of sending the information back to main view. But when I created a Navigation Controller as the popover and set the relationship to the old popover everything broke.

When I assign the delegate of the segue (shown above) it comes out on the other side as null so I completely lose my ability to pass it to other subviews and get information back to the main view. Does the Navigation Controller suck up the delegate? How do I get the delegate through the NC to the actual views?

I know this is Protocol and Delegate basics but I have looked around and can never seem to find an answer that has worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code out.

```
    NSArray *temp = [[segue destinationViewController] childViewControllers];
    PopoverViewController *popoverViewController = (PopoverViewController)[temp objectAtIndex:0];
    popoverViewController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much! I have been working on this for quite some time. I was hoping it would be a simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a navigation controller, create a delegate method in your main view that opens a different popover and closes the existing popover. You'll get the same result, but without the questionable idea of having a navigation controller in a popover.